# Flutter multiple drop-down issues

Tags: flutter, datatable, selection

I have made an data table in which I have made an drop-down which is in every row so  when I'm switching the value of drop-down in one drop-down then all the drop-downs value is getting changed so I want to stop the effect of that
The result is getting all drop-down values same on changing one drop downs value

```
final Map<String, IconData> symbolIconMapping = {
  "Mark": Icons.check, // You can set appropriate icons for each symbol
  "X": Icons.close,
  "-": Icons.line_axis,
  "DNS": Icons.dns,
  'r': Icons.some_icon_for_r, // Replace with the actual icon you want
};

String? _selectedSymbol;

DropdownButton<String>(
  value: _selectedSymbol,
  items: _symbols.map((String symbol) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: symbol,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        child: Text(symbol),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSymbol = value;
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: add minimal code for understanding of scenario